# ArcGIS 10.3 suddenly not reading .tif/.tiff rasters

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-10.3, geotiff-tiff

Anyone ever experience losing the ability to access .tif/.tiff rasters in ArcGIS/ArcCatalog? Both geotifs and general imagery tifs have become unusable, one day after I was able to access and use both. I have no problem seeing the tifs in ArcCatalog, but it seems as though the software doesn't recognize it as a viable file type anymore.

ArcCatalog tells me "your selection can't be displayed in the current view", and when I drag the files into ArcGIS, I am told that "Inavlid raster dataset. Unable to create raster layer".

I've tried many things to fix my problem with no luck: different file locations, different mxd, re-creating tifs and geotifs, importing new tifs, exporting and importing from different image types etc. There have been no software updates during this time.

Any ideas as to how to fix this?

Comment: What changes have been made to the system?  New software? New AV?  Please **edit** the question.

Comment: In Arcmap, did you try: Customize>Arcmap Options, Raster Dataset tab of the Raster tab, click File Formats button, Advanced>Restore Defaults?

Comment: @KirkKuykendall good idea, but sadly no luck.

Answer (score 1):

And like all ArcGIS problems, fully restarting my computer and connections has fixed everything. 
Thanks again for those who looked into this.